# Combining and mixing changes in version control?

Tags: git, svn, version-control

Since version control systems either store commits as lists of changes or are at least capable of figuring out the changes between different versions of a file, is it possible to pick any changes (not necessarily sequential) from any branches, as long as they all affect the same file, and apply them to any version of a file in any order, conflicts aside?

For example, let's say I have a file A with some initial content (version 0), then I make a branch and make some changes in both branches (versions 1, 2 and 1', 2'). Now I'd like to make a mix of the changes to get a "custom" version of the file A.

```
File A, version 0:
------------------
sample text
```

---

```
File A, version 1 (main branch):
------------------
sample text
new text 1        <-- added line
```

---

```
File A, version 2 (main branch):
------------------
sample text
new text 1
new text 2        <-- added line
```

---

```
File A, version 1' (new branch):
------------------
sample text
new text A        <-- added line
```

---

```
File A, version 2' (new branch):
------------------
sample text
new text A
new text B        <-- added line
```

Let's say I start with version 2 from the main branch and apply changes (in order): 2', 1. In this example I should get:

```
File A, "custom" version:
------------------
sample text
new text 1
new text 2
new text B
new text 1
```

Is something like this possible right now with SVN or git (or others), at least to some degree? Is something like this even possible (is it possible to create such a version control system)?

Answer (score 2):

Diffs in version control systems almost always include some context.  The diff doesn't say "add a line at the end of the file", but rather "add a line after the lines containing tthis text, and before the lines containing this other text".  For this reason, your specific example would result in conflicts, and the diffs would not apply cleanly.

If your diffs actual would apply cleanly, you can do this in most version control systems.  It's called "cherry picking", and is not limited to a single file.  You can also manually apply a diff, by asking you VCS for a unified diff between the revisions you are interested in and then use the `patch` command-line tool to apply that diff to the base state you like.